# One OSRM server for two modes of transportation?

Tags: openstreetmap

Is this possible to run one single OSRM server for both driving and walking modes? (perhaps even more)

https://github.com/Project-OSRM/osrm-backend

Documentation has an example with `nginx` routing between two OSRM  backends - one of driving, and another for walking. We'd like to avoid that and only run one backend for different modes of transportation.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Mostly a copy-paste of an answer I got on OSRM project -

Short answer is: no.

Few open-source routing engines can do that and always at the expense of runtime costs (i.e. takes longer to finish a request).

But there is [pgrouting](https://pgrouting.org/) (pinnacle of flexibility, relatively slow) and [valhalla](https://github.com/valhalla/valhalla) (good trade-off between flexibility & performance).

Comment: Credits: @nilsnolde